# Event not being added to Calendar on some Android phones

Tags: android, android-calendar

I am using below code to add events to calendar on android

```
public void addEvent(String datetime) { 
        String eventdate;
        {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");
        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        try {

            cal.setTime(formatter.parse(datetime));
            eventdate = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"/"+cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+"/"+cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+" "+cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+":"+cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            //Log.e("Event date ", eventdate);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Catch ", "",e);
        }
        ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
        event.put("calendar_id", 3);
        event.put("_id", eventid);
        event.put("title", mytitle);
        event.put("description", mydescription);
        event.put("eventTimezone", TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
        event.put("dtstart", cal.getTimeInMillis());
        event.put("dtend", cal.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000);
        event.put("hasAlarm", 1); // 0 for false, 1 for true

        String eventUriString = "content://com.android.calendar/events";

        Uri eventUri = getApplicationContext()
        .getContentResolver()
        .insert(Uri.parse(eventUriString), event);

        System.out.println("event"+eventUri);
    }
```

the following code adds event to my HTC phone running android lollipop but it returns null on Phones like Micromax and Samsung running android Jellybean. What can be the reason for this behavior? Do I need to turn anything on from settings?

Comment: Check whether this URI "content://com.android.calendar/events" is correct  for those devices.

Comment: use **Events.CONTENT_URI** instead of your uri

Comment: @JanithaR yes it is correct I am able to get calendar using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the constants provided by the `Events` class.

```
ContentResolver cr = yourContext.getContentResolver();
ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
event.put(Events.DTSTART,  cal.getTimeInMillis());
event.put(Events.DTEND, cal.getTimeInMillis() + 60 * 60 * 1000);
event.put(Events.TITLE, mytitle);
event.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, mydescription);
event.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID);
event.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
...
Uri uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, event);
```

The Event id of this inserted event can be get from this method

```
long eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
```

Check the title **Adding Events** in **Calendar Provider**
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html

If you want to insert an `_id` to the Event, you should check if it is already there

```
Uri event = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Events.CONTENT_URI, _id);
Cursor cursor = managedQuery(event, null, null, null);
if (cursor.getCount() == 1) {
  //the event exists.. so may be you want to update it
} else {
  // you can insert your id
}
```

Comment: don't I need to add a calendar id

Comment: ok that might be an issue?  then it wont be added to calendar I guess

Comment: nice code I am trying to use that. tnx for the idea